# When a user selects an item from dropdown list then that item must be removed for that user in mvc 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating a user course project for learning MVC 4. In this project, when a user logs in they can see their courses and other details. A user can create or edit the courses. So I am displaying list of courses in dropdown list during create and edit. What I want is, when a user selects a course and it is added to his list of courses then that course should not be displayed in the dropdown list for that user. Some code for create is given below:

CourseController:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    User user = (User)Session["User"];
    var usr = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
    if (Session["User"] != null)
    {             
        ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "CourseName");
        ViewBag.UserId = usr.UserId;
        ViewBag.FirstName = usr.FirstName;
    }
    return View();
}
//
// POST: /Course/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserCourse usercourse)
{
    User user = (User)Session["User"];
    var usr = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
    if (Session["User"] != null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.UserCourses.Add(usercourse);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "CourseName", usercourse.CourseId);
        ViewBag.UserId = usr.UserId;//from c in db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == usercourse.UserId) select c;
        ViewBag.FirstName = usr.FirstName;
        return View();
    }
    return View(usercourse);
}
```

Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CourseId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("CourseId", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseId)
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

Model class for User:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.UserCourses = new HashSet<UserCourse>();
    }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide User Name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; set; }
}
```

Model class for Course:

```
public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.UserCourses = new HashSet<UserCourse>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; set; }
}
```

Model class for UserCourse:

```
public partial class UserCourse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CourseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Please reply.

Comment: You should fetch those **courses** which are not selected (or added into user course selection table).

Comment: @AVD How can I do it? I am new to it so I would be grateful for a little more help

Comment: You need a query to get all courses and then exclude those courses that have already been assigned to the user.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know that I have to exclude the already selected courses but I don't know how to form a query for that purpose.

Comment: You have not given enough info to write the exact query, but first get the items to remove - `var userCouses = db.UserCourses.Where(x => x.UserId == userID).Select(x =>x.ID);` Then `var avaliableCourses = db.Courses.RemoveAll(x => userCouses.Contains(x));`

Comment: @StephenMuecke It says cannot convert lambda expression to type 'test.Models.Course' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Oops, that should have been `var avaliableCourses = db.Courses.RemoveAll(x => x.CourseId).Any(x => userCouses.Contains(x));` and the first one should be `.Select(x =>x.CourseId);` (I think :) - don't have time to test it right now)

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's ok I will try to do this and let you know

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is still giving the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]: Try it this way:

```
  public ActionResult Create()
{
    User user = (User)Session["User"];
    var usr = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
    if (Session["User"] != null)
    {   
        var courses = db.Courses.Where(x=>!x.UserCourses.Any(y=>y.CourseId == x.CourseId && y.UserId == usr.UserId)).ToList();

        ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(courses , "CourseId", "CourseName");
        ViewBag.UserId = usr.UserId;
        ViewBag.FirstName = usr.FirstName;
    }
    return View();
}
//
// POST: /Course/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserCourse usercourse)
{
    User user = (User)Session["User"];
    var usr = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
    if (Session["User"] != null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.UserCourses.Add(usercourse);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        var courses = db.Courses.Where(x=>!x.UserCourses.Any(y=>y.CourseId == x.CourseId && y.UserId == usr.UserId)).ToList();

        ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(courses, "CourseId", "CourseName", usercourse.CourseId);
        ViewBag.UserId = usr.UserId;//from c in db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == usercourse.UserId) select c;
        ViewBag.FirstName = usr.FirstName;
        return View();
    }
    return View(usercourse);
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but I am getting an error - The entity or complex type 'DetailsModel.UserCourse' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.